# General query for parsing in c using special character

Tags: parsing, input

Can we write a scanf function to parse input on # sign and read
two numbers?

since # is not used in aa standard way i am a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanf pattern `"%d#%d"` matches, in order:

- optional whitespace
- an integer
- the character `#`
- more optional whitespace
- another integer
  It returns 2 if both integers were found.

If there is anything (even a space character) between the first integer and the `#`, the scan will stop after the first integer and return 1. It will also stop and return 1 if whatever follows the `#` is not an integer possibly preceded by whitespace. This imprecision is one of the reasons scanf is often discouraged.

You could allow whitespace before the `#` by adding a space into the pattern: `"%d #%d"`. But whitespace includes newline characters, which can lead to unexpected behaviour. That's another reason scanf is often discouraged.

In summary:

- Yes, you can get scanf to read a line consisting of two numbers separated by a `#`. Not a problem; scanf does not have a concept of  "legal delimiter".
- If the input is from an error-prone source, such as a human typist, scanf makes it difficult to produce good error messages, which can be a frustrating experience. But if you know the input is error-free, scanf will work just fine.

In the above patterns, if you want to accept floating point numbers, change the `%d` to `%lf` (for doubles, generally recommended) or `%f` fir floats.